# iOS 8 update fails with network connection time out

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I am attempting to update my iPod touch 5th generation to iOS 8 but I am unable to do so.

When attempting to update over-the-air, I do not get very far into the updating process (still in the downloading phase) when a message pops up stating that the update failed (providing no reason).

I have also tried to update through iTunes 11.4 on my computer, however a message pops up stating that the network connection has timed out.

Are Apple's servers overwhelmed, or am I doing something wrong? I am unsure what to try next.

Comment: Can you please add some details about which installation steps you have already done and where/how exactly it is failing?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what is the problem, no one will be able to help you. Please consider adding a detailed explanation of the problem.

Comment: @cksum  I will put up some more details here shortly. I can't right now:)

Comment: @cksum How's that? :)

Comment: I've edited your question to attempt to clarify the intent—please feel free to edit further.

Comment: @grgarside Looks amazing! Thanks! :) I really didn't feel like doing any writing today. Now you see what happens when I don't feel like writing :)

Answer (score 1):

One known condition for the install is that the device must have ~5GB free space for the temporary download of the installer file. You should delete unused apps, music and photos/movies from your iPod before you run the installation. The iPod should give you an error message saying the device doesn't have enough room.

Comment: or try it from iTunes, 4 in the morning, pacific time, using 'download only'

Comment: Might have to try that!